# Content depended width of <div> under another <div>

Tags: html, css

[image: Example]

Hello, I am new to HTML and CSS. I want to make the `div` width dependent on the size of the content in it, and they must display under each other. I tried to use `display: inline-block`, but that makes the description move to the header. If I don't use `display: inline-block`, the width of the `div` is incorrect. If I set it to auto, the width of `div` becomes the width of `bottom_part`.

```
<div class="slider_test">
    <div class="slide_test">
        <a class="slide_img_link" href="http://google.com">
            <img src="cat.png" class="slide_img">
        </a>
        <div class="bottom_part">
            <div class="bottom_text1">
                <h4>Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom_text2">
                <p1>Description</p1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.slider_test {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
}

.slide_test {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%
}

.slide_img_link {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.slide_img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.bottom_part {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
}

.bottom_text1 {
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}

.bottom_text1 h4 {
    margin: 0;
}

.bottom_text2 {
    background-color: aqua;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Does anyone know how I can go about displaying this as intended?

Comment: @uttejh when i use this i have correct width of <div> but they displays in one line. But i need them under each other.

Comment: use `clear:both` along with float, it should solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place `Description` `div` inside an another `div` and set the `display` of both `Header` and `Description` `div` to `inline-block`

```css
.slider_test {
width: 600px;
height: 300px;
}

.slide_test {
position: relative;
height: 100%
}

.slide_img_link {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.slide_img {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.bottom_part {
position: absolute;
height: 50%;
width: 50%;
bottom: 0;
}

.bottom_text1 {
background-color: red;
vertical-align: top;
width: auto;
bottom: 0;
display: inline-block;
}

.bottom_text1 h4 {
margin: 0;
}

.bottom_text2 {
background-color: aqua;
vertical-align: top;
width: auto;
bottom: 0;
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider_test">
<div class="slide_test">
    <a class="slide_img_link" href="http://google.com">
        <img src="cat.png" class="slide_img">
    </a>
    <div class="bottom_part">
        <div class="bottom_text1"><h4>Header</h4>
        </div>
      <div>
        <div class="bottom_text2">
            <p1>Description</p1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `float` - the element will act as `inline`. And `clear:both` to clear the row of any elements on both sides.

```css
.slider_test {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
}

.slide_test {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%
}

.slide_img_link {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.slide_img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.bottom_part {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
}

.bottom_text1 {
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: auto;
    bottom: 0;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.bottom_text1 h4 {
    margin: 0;
}

.bottom_text2 {
    background-color: aqua;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: auto;
    bottom: 0;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider_test">
    <div class="slide_test">
        <a class="slide_img_link" href="http://google.com">
            <img src="cat.png" class="slide_img">
        </a>
        <div class="bottom_part">
            <div class="bottom_text1"><h4>Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom_text2">
                <p1>Description</p1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the width and add a flex on .bottom-part

```
.bottom_part {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```